# Magical Subarrays in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, logic

Can someone explain how to solve the question below, Much appreciated!

Given an integer array[] of size n, your task is to count the number of magical subarrays in the arr.

Here any subarray array[l…r] is considered to be magical if it satisfies the magical condition.

it should contain an even number(non zero) of odd numbers

More Formally the count of odd numbers in the subarray should be even and should be greater than 0

```
Constraints
1<=n<=10^5
1<=array[i]<=2*(10)^5
```

```
#TestCase 1;
Input:
n=4
array[]={2,1,2,3}

output:2
the magical subarrays are: {2,1,2,3} , {1,2,3}
```

```
#Testcase 2
n=6
array[]={1,2,5,2,3,7}

output:7
the magical subarrays are:{1,2,5}, {1,2,5,2}, {2,5,2,3}, {5,2,3}, {2,3,7}, {3,7}, {1,2,5,2,3,7}
```

The code below gives TLE for the above constraints

```
 long long magicalSubarrays(int n,vector<int> arr)
    
    {
        vector<int> O;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
            O.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        int k=O.size();
        long long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < O.size(); i++) {
             for (int j = i + 1; j < O.size(); j += 2) {
                int left = (i-1<0)? O[i]: O[i]-1-O[i-1];
                int right= (j+1>=k)? n-1-O[j]: O[j+1]-1-O[j];
      
                    sum += (1 + left) * (1 + right);
            }
        }
        return sum;
       
      
    }
```

Comment: Can you tag the programming language? From the input it looks like it could be java or c++... I removed the `dsa` tag as it is not related to Digital Signature Algorithm. It would also be good to include the code you have tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Let `O` be the array that contains all indices of odd elements.
Every magical subarray must then consist of:

- every number from O[i] to O[j] inclusive (where j = i+1+2*k for some k)
- an arbitrary number of even items left of i
- an arbitrary number of even items right of j

Or, in C++-flavored pseudocode:

```
int magical_subarrays(const std::vector<int>& arr) {
  std::vector<size_t> O;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
      O.push_back(i);
    }
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < O.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < O.length(); j += 2) {
      int left = /* exercise for the reader. It involves O[i] and O[i-1]. */
      int right = /* exercise for the reader. It involves O[j] and O[j+1]. */
      sum += (1 + left) * (1 + right);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I completed the above code but it wasn't able to pass all the testcases since its giving a TLE

Comment: Is your calculation of `left` and `right` O(1)? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Yes the calculations were in constant time, I have provided the code that I executed in the question

Comment: Time to whip out another staple of competitive programming. Have you noticed that your inner loop computes the same subsolution over and over?